# finding the maximum number of pieces that can be cut from one single wood

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Sorry for this type of question but I am searching for an established algorithm for a problem like below. I could not find a name. The question is below

A good chair is vital to engineering productivity.
You are buying wood and trying to make a chair yourself!

The home improvement store has a lot of wood of exactly length L.
According to the design, you need exactly mm pieces of wood of length a[i] to build the chair.

You are free to cut the wood bought from the home improvement store as much as you like.
For example, you can cut a piece of wood of length 5 into lengths of 1,4 or lengths of 1,3,1

What is the minimum number of pieces of wood you need to buy at the home improvement store in order to complete the chair?

Implementation
CLI
Build the solution as a CLI application that receives input values from stdin and returns the expected output to stdout. For details, see the "Command line application template" section at the bottom of this page.

Input
Standard input

a[1] ... a[m] L

1≤m≤10, integer

1≤a[i]≤L, integer

1≤L≤100, integer

Output
Print in the 1st line the minimum number of pieces of wood you need to buy to make the chair.

I/O Examples
You can find expected pairs of input and output in the test/ directory. Please refer to this directory when implementing.

I/O Example 1

Standard input

3 5 2 10

Standard output

1

If you buy 1 piece of wood of length 10 and cut it into the lengths 3, 5, 2 you have enough wood to complete the chair.

I/O Example 2

Standard input

6 7 6 10

Standard output

3

It is necessary to buy 3 pieces of wood. Cutting in the manner of [10,10,10]→[6,4,7,3,6,4], you will have enough wood to complete the chair.
In this case, pieces of the lengths 4,3,4 will be leftover.

I/O Example 3

Standard input

6 7 4 10

Standard output

2

In this case, you can cut a piece of wood of length 10 into the lengths 6,4.
By cutting in the manner of [10,10]→[6,4,3,7], you will have enough wood to complete the chair. In this case, a piece of length 3 is left over.

My approach(pseudo code):

int c_number_of_wood_needed ==1

int remaining_piece=Max_length

sort(array_of_pieces)

for each PIECE in array_of_pieces:

```
 if remaining_piece>=PIECE:
 remaining_piece=remaining_piece-PIECE

 else:
 remaining_piece==Max_length
 c_number_of_wood_needed++
 remaining_piece=remaining_piece-PIECE
```

Comment: This is basically a problem of finding the maximum number of pieces that can be cut from one single wood

Comment: It's a bin packing problem. If you need a large number of pieces in duplicate, it's also a cutting stock problem.

Comment: Thanks man. That is the answer I needed

Comment: See also 'Knapsack Problem' for a similar probpem.